# How can I scp using a "do until loop"?

Tags: scp

This `scp` command fails nearly daily:

```
scp myfile root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/myhome
```

Sometimes, I have to do it 2-3 times as it does not make the network connection off and on.  How can I put this into a loop, like a "do until loop" so it keeps running the `scp` command until it succeeds?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: [Tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) is a good place to start to understand what is going on here ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a basic `while` loop for this:

```
while ! scp myfile root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/myhome; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `until scp myfile root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/myhome; do :; done`?